# Determine if points are within a rotated rectangle

Tags: python, python-2.x, mathematics, jython

*Using only Python 2.7 and the standard library (no imports):*

[Determine if a point is inside the rotated rectangle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537720/10936066)

```
Test point 1: 670831  4867989
Test point 2: 675097  4869543

Rectangle:

Vertex 1:     670273   4879507
Vertex 2:     677241   4859302
Vertex 3:     670388   4856938
Vertex 4:     663420   4877144
```

---

Can the following code be improved?

```
vertices = [(670273, 4879507), (677241, 4859302), (670388, 4856938), (663420, 4877144)]

def dot_pdt(point1, point2, pointT):
    return ((point2[0] - point1[0]) * (pointT[0] - point1[0])) + ((point2[1] - point1[1]) * (pointT[1] - point1[1]))

def check_point(pointT):
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        k = dot_pdt(vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % len(vertices)], pointT)
        if k <= 0:
            return False

    return True

point1 = (676455.270, 4861545.437)

print(check_point(point1))
```

Comment: `return not any(dot_pdt(v, v_next, pointT) <= 0 for v, v_next in zip(vertices, vertices[1:] + vertices[:0]))`

Comment: The answer provided by Yves Daoust in the link you gave is pretty much as good as you'll find. Is there a reason you don't believe so?

Comment: @IEatBagels : It's a good answer, but Yves Daoust didn't actually provide code, so that's why I made my own. I'm not a great coder so I thought I'd get it reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

### Code Review

- **Main guard**

When running code outside a function / class, it is a good practice to put the code inside the *main guard*. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) for more explanation.

- **Docstrings**

It is a good practice to provide docstrings for functions. See [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/docstrings-python) for more details. In Python 3.5+, adding [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to function parameters and return values is also a good habit. (As a side remark, Python 2 has officially [reached the end of life](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases). It is recommended to move to Python 3.)

- **Variable & function names should be clear, descriptive, and unambiguous**

For example, `check_point` could be named as `is_inside_rectangle`.

- **Function definition should include all necessary parameters**

`vertices` should be a parameter of the function `check_point`.

- **Other minor improvements**

By exploiting the fact that `vertices[-1]` is the same as `vertices[len(vertices)-1]`, the explicit modulo operation `vertices[(i + 1) % len(vertices)]` could be avoided.

The `for`-loop logic can be simplified using an `all` statement.

Here is an improved version of the code:

```
def dot_prod_with_shared_start(start, end1, end2):
    """
    Compute the dot product of the vectors pointing from start to end1 and end2

    Parameters
        start: starting point of both vectors
        end1: end point of first vector
        end2: end point of second vector

    Returns
        dot product of (end1 - start) and (end2 - start)
    """
    return (end1[0] - start[0]) * (end2[0] - start[0]) + (end1[1] - start[1]) * (end2[1] - start[1])

def is_inside_rectangle(vertices, point):
    """
    Given the vertices of a rectangle, determine whether a point is inside it.

    Parameters
        vertices: a list of tuples representing rectangle vertices in clockwise or
                  counter-clockwise order
        point: a tuple representing the point to check

    Returns
        True if the point is inside the rectangle. False otherwise.
    """
    return all(dot_prod_with_shared_start(vertices[i - 1], v, point) > 0 for i, v in enumerate(vertices))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   rect_vertices = [(670273, 4879507), (677241, 4859302), (670388, 4856938), (663420, 4877144)]
   test_point = (676455.270, 4861545.437)

   print(is_inside_rectangle(rect_vertices, test_point))
```

### Another Solution

An alternative solution is to represent the vertices and the point as complex values, and apply complex number arithmetics to solve the problem.

```
def is_directed_angle_acute(start, end1, end2):
    """
    Check whether the directed angle from (end1 - start) to (end2 - start) is an acute angle, 
    i.e. within (0, pi / 4).

    Parameters
        start: a complex value representing the starting point of both vectors
        end1: a complex value representing the end point of first vector
        end2: a complex value representing the end point of second vector

    Returns
        True if the directed angle from (end1 - start) to (end2 - start) is within (0, pi / 4).
        False otherwise.
    """
    q = (end2 - start) / (end1 - start)
    return q.real > 0 and q.imag > 0

def is_inside_rectangle(vertices, point):
    """
    Given the vertices of a rectangle, determine whether a point is inside it.

    Parameters
        vertices: a list of complex values representing rectangle vertices in clockwise order
        point: a complex value representing the point to check

    Returns
        True if the point is inside the rectangle. False otherwise.
    """
    v0, v1, v2, v3 = vertices
    return is_directed_angle_acute(v0, point, v1) and is_directed_angle_acute(v2, point, v3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   rect_vertices = [670273 + 4879507j, 677241 + 4859302j, 670388 + 4856938j, 663420 + 4877144j]
   test_point = 676455.270 + 4861545.437j

   print(is_inside_rectangle(rect_vertices, test_point))
```